# Trouble with stdClass Object Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have one Array. It return this values:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
  (
     [seccionalid] => 1
     [seccionaldescricao] => DELSECPOL DE SJRIO PRETO
  )

[1] => stdClass Object
  (
     [seccionalid] => 2
     [seccionaldescricao] => DELSECPOL DE JALES
  )

[2] => stdClass Object
  (
     [seccionalid] => 3
     [seccionaldescricao] => DELSECPOL DE ARAÇATUBA
  )
```

I trying return with echo or print_r, all values of [seccionaldescricao] of Array:

```
$dados = $seccionais->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$dados2 = $dados[0]->seccionaldescricao;

print_r($dados2);
```

But, returned only one row:

```
2DELSECPOL DE SJRIOPRETO
```

I liked know, how returning all values [seccionaldescricao] of Array e why the number 2(two) is description concatenaded;

Comment: It is because You take first element from `$dados`

Comment: FYI: You can take a quick tour here to get an overview of the site: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: So where are we with this question ?

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through all inner objects with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and return the property, e.g.

```
$dados2 = array_map(function($v){
    return $v->seccionaldescricao;
}, $dados);
```